# Real world examples of GraphQL-Ruby APIs to learn from?

Tags: graphql, graphql-ruby

What are some of the best real world open source API implementations using Graphql-Ruby?

I came across this articles which signifies 5 examples of Javascript Graphql APIs to learn from.
https://dev.to/gethackteam/5-examples-of-javascript-graphql-apis-to-learn-from-31gf

Looking for similar real world & open source API implementations using Graphql-Ruby. Please mention the link if you know one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitlab uses GraphQL and their source code is open source, so you can check it out [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/app/graphql).

Besides that, i know that Shopify and Github use GraphQL for their public APIs, but their APIs are not open sourced.

If you want to do a bit of digging, you could leverage the [Dependants part of the Github page for GraphQL-Ruby](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/network/dependents) to check which open source projects are using it.